# Action Script: Can't get API mod to work in Scratch

Tags: flash, actionscript, mit-scratch

I've been trying to make a mod for [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu) that would use the website's [API](http://api.scratch.mit.edu) to pull information about user's. The problem is that I've had to break it into two blocks. (These blocks work by calling functions based on a table with block names and function names, and passes in the arguments.) I've set it up where the first one (which calls primAskAboutMe) loads the information from the API, and then when the information loads, the user can use the second block (which calls primReportAboutMe) to return the value. The problem is that I can't get the second block to return an answer.

So either I'm trying to get information the wrong way, (which is possible because this is the first time I've used Action Script/Flash or whatever,) or I really don't understand what I'm doing.

*Note: [Original Scratch Repository](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-flash). This code would be found in src/primitives/Primitives.as (but isn't because I haven't uploaded this yet to my own repository, because I'm not really sure how).

```
protected var resultAM:String;

    protected function primAskAboutMe(b:Block):void {
var user:String = interp.arg(b, 0);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:String = 'http://www.api.scratch.mit.edu/users/'+user;
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteAboutMe );
    loader.load(urlReq);



}
protected function onCompleteAboutMe(e:Event):void{
    //resultAM = e.target.data;
    resultAM="foo";
    }

protected function primReportAboutMe():String{


return resultAM;


}
```

Comment: Anyone? Does this have a bump feature? Hellooooo?

Comment: What is your Scratch script? Perhaps the data hasn't yet loaded when you try and access it. Click edit on the post above to add that in, and then reply to my comment.

Comment: No, there is no bump feature. You get an answer when a **volunteer** feels like dealing with your question. So you _"can't get the second block to return an answer"_, what does that mean exactly? You get a string but it's empty? Or you you mean you cannot run the function at all? Before you do line `return resultAM;` add the line `trace ("Result AM is : " + resultAM);`. What does it say about result?

Comment: My apologies @VC.One I'll get back to you once I do those tests.

Comment: @VC.One Nothing appeared in the console. It didn't change the value of the variable in Scratch. I've tried many different setups which should allow enough time to load.

Comment: So your debugger didn't show any text like `Result AM is :` etc? That means maybe the function didn't even run at all? At what point (not shown in your code) are you even running that **primReportAboutMe** function? The code for that should look like `resultAM="foo";` now also add the following line `primReportAboutMe();` (which runs this function). Now do you get a feedback `Result AM is :` etc etc....

Comment: @VC.One Ten seconds after I used primAskAboutMe is when I ran primReportAboutMe. I also added 'resultAM = "loader sent";' at the en of primAskAboutMe which made no change.

Comment: I added 5 traces, and the first one, which is now the first line of code in 'primAskAboutMe' would not show in the console. I'm going to check some code that calls it but based on how picky gradle has been when compiling I can't imagine anything is wrong with it. Actually, 'primReportAboutMe' didn't trigger it's trace blocks either...

Comment: My bad... I should have mentioned you update an existing String variable with the `return` result... something like `myString = primReportAboutMe();`. See the basic test in my Answer. Also consider making your functions as `public` instead of `protected` just incase that status affects anything (it shouldn't, but you never know). You can always change back to protected functions once you're sure everything else works fine...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't get the second block to return an answer.

I think it's because you haven't set a receiver for the returned result. If you make a Report string then update like `str_Report = primReportAboutMe();` this will return text of `resultAM` into `str_Report`.

Here is a small testable example. Maybe it will help you in some way...
Remember since `primReportAboutMe` returns String data it must be used to update some String **variable**.

```
var resultAM:String = "";
var checkResult:String = "";

resultAM="foo";

checkResult = primReportAboutMe(); //# update this String with function returned String
trace ("Check Result is : " + checkResult); //# shows... Check Result is : foo

function primReportAboutMe():String
{
    return resultAM; //# returns a String's current value
}
```